# Comparing two unsigned char buffers

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have two CVImageBufferRef buffers that correspond to two images grabbed in sequence by AVCaptureSession. I would like to compare both to see if all the pixels are the same. In order to loop thru all pixels of the frame buffer and compare them, I have this:

```
unsigned char *pixelA = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferA);
unsigned char *pixelB = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferB);


- (BOOL) isBuffer:(unsigned char *)pixelA equalToBuffer:(unsigned char *)pixelB {
    for( int row = 0; row < bufferHeight; row++ ) {
        for( int column = 0; column < bufferWidth; column++ ) {

            if ((pixelA[0] != pixelB[0]) ||
                (pixelA[1] != pixelB[1]) ||
                (pixelA[2] != pixelB[2]) ){
                return NO; 
                // means at some point pixelA is not equal to pixelB, so
                // pixelBufferA is not equal to pixelBufferB
            }

            pixelA += BYTES_PER_PIXEL;
            pixelB += BYTES_PER_PIXEL;

        }
    }

        // if the method reached here, pixelBufferA is equal to pixelBufferB, so
        return YES; // are equal
}
```

Obviously it is crashing in the comparison. How do I compare all values in pixelA with pixelB ? thanks

Comment: Have you figured out how far you get before it craps out?

Comment: Have you verified that the addresses you're getting are even valid?  Used the debugger to display what they are and what they point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually done what you're doing, but is there a reason you can't just compare the buffers in one go, say, with `memcmp`?

```
- (BOOL) isBuffer:(unsigned char*)pixelA equalToBuffer:(unsigned char*)pixelB
{
    size_t bufferSize = bufferWidth * bufferHeight * BYTES_PER_PIXEL;

    return memcmp( pixelA, pixelB, bufferSize ) == 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 was composing the very same reply.  it might be safer (and faster) to first compare the sizes of each buffer.  bail with NO if the sizes don't match.  maybe pixel buffers are always the same size?  not sure.

Comment: Can't do that. Both images have the same width, height and bytes per pixels... **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper -- If both images have the same dimensions, why can't you just do one bulk compare?

Comment: sorry about the comment, I was thinking another thing. Your answer is correct. Thanks.